# Serve Flask application with GUnicorn on Localhost

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I am a noob in this area so please bear with my dumb questions.

I have a Flask application and I want to run that with GUnicorn on my localhost. I looked on Google but almost every tutorial requires a domain name and there isn't much documentation for running it on a mac.

1. Please tell how can I run the app with GUnicorn on my mac?
2. I want to use https for the secure communication so how can I change the configuration of Gunicorn to do so?

Any help will be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to run it on your localhost you don't need any domain name. You just have to run Python file where you have configured your flask app on your terminal and then you will get a port number where application will be running on your local machine.

Steps to run app

1. Change your current directory of your terminal to directory where your project is present, using

   ```sh
   cd <your directory address>
   ```
2. Now run your app using

   ```sh
   python ./<file_name>.Py
   ```

Note: If you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed (Your machine comes with a version of Python 2 but you can install Python 3 as well), you should run

```sh
python3 <file_name>.py
```

Even if you want to deploy on web on a server without your domain name for free you can do it using heroku or any other service as you like.

Running a Flask application on gunicorn is quite simple:

```sh
gunicorn <file_name>:app
```

Gunicorn provides many command-line options – see `gunicorn -h`. For example, to run a Flask application with 4 worker processes (`-w 4`) binding to `localhost` on port 4000 (`-b 127.0.0.1:4000`):

```sh
gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:4000 <file_name>:app
```

Comment: I am able to run the app, but not in Gunicorn environment.

Comment: And please also answer the 2nd question.

Comment: I have added the answer to your second question check if it works works for you.